# Use of Might have

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, grammaticality

Although the construction began in the year 2009,(but) the building came into commercial use only in 2014.

Although the construction might have begun in the year 2009,(but) the building came into commercial use only in 2014.

What does the word 'might have'  mean in the second sentence and can we use but with although?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"might have" here simply indicates the writer is not completely sure when the construction began.

I would not use "but" in either of these sentences, the word "Although" implies a "but" idea is coming without directly writing it.